# Create R53 ALIAS record set, to point to S3 bucket hosting a static website using Boto2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I am creating a S3 bucket and configure it to serve static website via boto2.

I want to create a R53 ALIAS record set that will connect the S3 bucket name (eg `something.some.com`) with the same subdomain (`something.some.com`).

I wrote the following piece of code but it returns an error.

```
changes = boto.route53.record.ResourceRecordSets(R53conn, HostedZone_id)
change  = changes.add_change(
    action="CREATE",
    name="something.some.com",
    type="A",
    alias_hosted_zone_id=HostedZone_id,
    alias_dns_name='s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    alias_evaluate_target_health=False
)
result = changes.commit()
```

and the error I get is

```
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto\route53\connection.py", line 475, in change_rrsets
    body)
boto.route53.exception.DNSServerError: DNSServerError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://route53.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-04-01/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>InvalidChangeBatch</Code><Message>Tried to create an alias that targets s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com., type A in zone Z26JTS7LAE8OIN, but the alias target name does not lie within the target zone</Message></Error><RequestId>74e609ed-be51-11e6-99bd-69e41e07a223</RequestId></ErrorResponse>
```

which I cannot understand... . What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I could not make progress with Boto2 so I solved it with Boto3 (far better).

Here is the code:

```
Route53_Hosted_Zone_ID = "Z3AQBSTGFYJSTF" #Notice: Fixed ID for us-east-1
Custom_HZ_id = "use_yours"

record_set_obj = clientR53.change_resource_record_sets(
    HostedZoneId=Custom_HZ_id,
    ChangeBatch={
        'Changes': [
            {
            'Action': 'CREATE',
            'ResourceRecordSet': {
                                'Name': client_bucket_name,
                                'Type': 'A',
                                'AliasTarget': {
                                                'HostedZoneId': Route53_Hosted_Zone_ID,
                                                'DNSName': 's3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
                                                'EvaluateTargetHealth': False
                                               },
                }
            },
        ]
    }
)
```

I hope it will help someone :]